# return value of mxGetPr() -- equivalent looping

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I am trying to implement a `mexFunction()` into "pure" C++ (OpenCV), but the returned value by `mxGetPr()` is not clear at all for me.

The following code is aimed to be implemented:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
    {

       int *D = new int[N*L];

       // where N and L are dimensions (cols and rows) of matrix prhs[3] 
       // prhs[3] is a NxL matrix containing floating point value

       for (int i=0; i<N*L; i++)
           D[i] = mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i];


    }
```

My question is, what kind of value is given by `mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i]` and `mxGetPr(prhs[4])[i]`? And how is it looping through matrix?

I tried to do something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
       {
           D[iCounter] = (int)d.at<uchar>(i,j);
           iCounter++;
       }
   }
```

Looping through `d` matrix which is the same as input value `prhs[3]`, but apparently it is not correct.
I guess the order/type of the returned value is not the same as in the original `mexFunction`.

**EDIT**

Now I have cv::Mat d; instead of prhs[3] and try to do the same as in mexfunction.

```
int *D = new int[N*L];

int iCounter = 0;

for (int i=0; i<L; i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
       {
           D[iCounter] = (int)d.at<uchar>(i,j);
           iCounter++;
       }
   }
```

But here (int)d.at(i,j) returns value of the "d" matrix...where in the roiginal code a pointer was returned by mxGetPr().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mxGetPr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html) returns a pointer of type `double` so you can access your data using pointer arithmetic.  Also, you must remember that the pointer returned to you has the data in **column-major** order.  This means that you must traverse your data row-wise instead of column-wise like in traditional C order.

In column-major order, you access location `(i, j)` with the following linear index:

```
j * rows + i
```

`rows` is the number of rows in your matrix, with `i` and `j` being the row and column you want to access.  In row-major or C order, the way you access data is:

```
i * cols + j
```

Here `cols` is the number of columns in your matrix.  I'm assuming you want to lay out your data in row-major format rather than column major.  Therefore if you want to loop through the data using two `for` loops, do something like this:

```
double *ptr = mxGetPr(prhs[3]);

// A L x N matrix - L rows, N columns
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        D[i * N + j] = (int) ptr[j * L + i];
    }
}
```

Here `D` is a pointer pointing to integer data. You have to cast the data in order to do this as the pointer to the data from MATLAB is already `double`. It's nasty but that's what you have to do. You can use `D` in row-major order so it's compatible with the rest of your code.  I'm assuming that you are using MATLAB MEX as way of making pre-written C++ code to be interfaced with MATLAB.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. *D a pointer to a container with int values. But the input matrix is having floating point values, so what mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i] is returning to D[i] actually? Could you please help me?

Comment: @Kristan Just cast the data to `int` before storing. I'll edit my post.  It's not safe, but that's what you do.  Is the input matrix coming from MATLAB **also** floating-point?  That is, when you call your MEX function, is the input type of the third input parameter into your MEX function **also** of type `double` or floating-point?  That is important before I edit my post.

Comment: Yes, the input matrix has floating point values. What I would like to do is that instead of using mxGetPr(), I would like to use some other (preferably OpenCV) function to return the same value as mxGetPr() does. The reason is that I will not use anymore the original Matlab code, but "purely" C++(OpenCV).

Comment: You'd have to copy the data into a `cv::Mat` before using any of the OpenCV methods on it. I'll edit my post but all you do is cast the data.

Comment: sure, now I use cv::Mat for containing elements. and what i want to do is looping over this matrix and returning the same value as mxGetPr() does.

Comment: Ok so is `D` actually a `cv::Mat`?? That is different entirely. Is it your intent to copy the data from MATLAB to a `cv::Mat` container? You should have explicitly said so your question. It changes the answer entirely. Please clarify for me because I'm confused with what you want. OpenCV will never return what MATLAB gives you.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. So initially prhs[3] was a MATLAB matrix, and used in mexFunction() for process. But now I implemented everything in C++(OpenCV) so I have cv::Mat d .The type of int*D did not change. I would like to process "d" similarly way as it was with the input Matlab matrix. As I understand in the mexFunction() mxGetPr() returned double* and gave it to D[i]. Now, I would like to return the same value but using OpenCV function -I guess somehow accessing pointers to the elements-.

Comment: So you want a pointer to the actual data instead? OpenCV can only do this on a row basis. You can only get a pointer to one row of data at a time. What's the problem with using the `at` method to get your data?

Comment: Now I am confused, in the mexFunction() D[i] gets a pointer or data by mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i];? It is important because later D is an input into another function...

Comment: No, you're copying a value stored at the memory pointed to by `mxGetPr` into the allocated memory in `D`. I think I'll stop here. I don't know what you want and maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: appreciate your help now it is getting clear, hat happens when continuing someone else coding...confusion. but thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: You're welcome. I suppose I didn't answer your question but I guess I helped in some way.